# Trying to create a calander table in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was given an assignment to display a calendar I js. so got the first day of the month and tried to make a table using the logic described in the code below. For some reason the below code doesn't print anything except for the head of the table.

```js
var year = parseFloat(prompt("Enter Year: "))
var month = parseFloat(prompt("Enter Month in number: "))
var firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();
showcalander(firstDay);

function showcalander(day) {
  tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body").innerHTML = "";
  let date = 1;
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
      if (i == 1 && j < day) {
        cell = document.createElement("td");
        cellText = document.createTextNode("");
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
      } else if (date > 30) {
        break;
      } else {
        cell = document.createElement("td");
        cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        date++;
      }

    }
    tbl.appendChild(row);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sun</th>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
      <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="calendar-body"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line :

```
tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body").innerHTML = ""
```

That should be :

```
tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body")
```

```js
var year = parseFloat(prompt("Enter Year: "))
var month = parseFloat(prompt("Enter Month in number: "))
var firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();
showcalander(firstDay);

function showcalander(day) {
  tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body");
  let date = 1;
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
      if (i == 1 && j < day) {
        cell = document.createElement("td");
        cellText = document.createTextNode("");
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
      } else if (date > 30) {
        break;
      } else {
        cell = document.createElement("td");
        cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        date++;
      }

    }
    tbl.appendChild(row);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sun</th>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
      <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="calendar-body"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: To fix the logic, use total = new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate() to get the number of days in month, and use it instead of hard-coding 30 which is wrong.